# Simple MVC Razor rendering view issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am learning MVC with Razor and have a simple question (I think). I am having trouble displaying the contents of a model in the view and am not sure why.

My view is a .cshtml page.
I am passing a model to it that is of type IEnumerable

I cannot get the 'foreach' statement to run in the below view. Interesting the <% characters are not coloured yellow in Visual Studio so I think I may have missed something. Any ideas? Here is my view code...

```
@model IEnumerable<HERE_MVC.Models.CheckIn>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Home - Main page</h2>

<% foreach (var checkIn in Model.CheckIn){ %>
   <li><%: checkIn.ID %></li>   
<% } %>
```

And my controller code looks like this...

```
    public ActionResult Home(string lat, string lon)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to HERE!";

        HEREModel m = new HEREModel();
        var v1 = m.GetEntitiesByLatLon(lat, lon);
        return View(v1);
    }
```

Thank you in advance, I've been trying to work this out for a while but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brush up on your Razor syntax -- Razor doesn't use bee stings (<%). Try this:

```
@model IEnumerable<HERE_MVC.Models.CheckIn>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Home - Main page</h2>

@foreach (var checkIn in Model.CheckIn) {
   <li>@checkIn.ID</li>   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<% foreach (var checkIn in Model.CheckIn){ %> 
    <li><%: checkIn.ID %></li>    
<% } %>
```

to this:

```
@foreach (var checkIn in Model.CheckIn) { 
   <li> @checkIn.ID </li>    
}
```

Pre-processor directives from aspx are no longer used, now the @ is used. Check this [**article**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) from Scott Gu, it explains the use of the Razor View engine syntax.