# InsufficentExecutionStackException in MVC Razor file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

So I am trying to work with asp net mvc 4.5 and I am working inside my login razor view. This page is different from the rest so I have at the top

```
@model HSServer.Models.LoginModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
    Layout = null;
}
```

with `Layout = null;` so that it does not use a master page.

I try to run the application and it throws a InsufficentExecutionStackException on the line `Layout = null;` and says

```
Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from
having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too
much stack space.
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on!

**EDIT**

It appears that its not related to the `Layout = null` as removing that did not help and simply moved the error up one line. Still digging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. I duplicated [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196610/simple-mvc-razor-rendering-view-issue?rq=1) without knowing it.

In the body I was calling `@Html.Action("Login")` and not `@Url.Action("Login")` like I meant to. The page was recursively calling itself instead of simply giving my a url... Whoops.